# Is there any way to add some controls before commit in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

We are changing our technology from c# to Java. We are using IntelliJ Community Edition as IDE. While using Visual Studio, we have custom check in policies to avoid developers from doing things we don't want according to our standards. We also want this for IntelliJ before commits. We want to protect our project structure according to our standards. Is there any way to realize my this wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is generally possible, but implementation depends on the VCS in use.

E.g. in Git, one can use local (to verify on commit, e.g. `pre-commit`) and server-side (to prevent pushing incorrect changes, e.g. `pre-recieve`) [hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

IF TFS is used, existing TFS integration plugins allow implementing custom Checkin policies as additional custom plugins. There are some [implemented already](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9985-check-in-policies-for-tfs-team-foundation-server-)